# How to add and then remove a class as user scrolls down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me code an animation feature? I am trying to figure out how to code a piece of paper exiting a slot coming towards the user on the screen (3D) as the user scrolls down. In other words, scrolling controls the paper’s movement in and out of the slot. The first six seconds of this video demonstrates what I mean. THANK YOU! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i86Q3v3scjk

I don’t have any idea how to do this, but I tried by creating several images, representing each stage of the paper’s position as it exits the slot, to the HTML and setting each image as its own class. I thought if I did it this way, I could control the classes being added and removed as the user scrolls down, giving the effect of a smooth animated piece of paper. Unfortunately it didn’t  work. Does anyone have a answer? I am looking for the best solution.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

    const position_1 = document.querySelector('position_1');

 if(window.scrollY = 1) {  child.classList.add('position_1');}

 else if(window.scrollY = 2){
 child.classList.remove('position_1');
}

 if(window.scrollY = 2) {  child.classList.add('position_2');
 }

 else if(window.scrollY = 3){
 child.classList.remove('position_2');
 }

 if(window.scrollY = 3) {  child.classList.add('position_3');
 }

 else if(window.scrollY = 4){
  child.classList.remove('position_3');
  }

  if(window.scrollY = 4) {  child.classList.add('position_4');
 }

 else if(window.scrollY = 5){
  child.classList.remove('position_4');
  }

  if(window.scrollY = 5) {  child.classList.add('position_5');
}

else if(window.scrollY = 6){
  child.classList.remove('position_5');
  }

  if(window.scrollY = 6) {  child.classList.add('position_6');
}



  window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    console.log(scrolled);
  });})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 place-items: center;
}

.one {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.three {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scroll card flip</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<body>
  
  <section class="one">
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="position_1">
      <img src="position_1.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_2">
      <img src="position_2.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_2">
      <img src="position_2.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_3">
      <img src="position_3.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_4">
      <img src="position_4.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_5">
      <img src="position_5.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="position_6">
      <img src="position_6.png"> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="two">
  </section>
  <section class="three">
  </section>
  
  <script  src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: = is assignment, not comparison....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use multiple images. The trick is to use CSS [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) and [transform-style: preserve-3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style).
Here's a very simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-reveal-animation-zpktly?file=/src/styles.css
I included comments in the `script.js` file. Hope it will help, good luck!